# Expected time of n events to complete

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poissons-equation

What is the expected time do i have to wait until n events are completed each distributed in exponential time $\mu$?

I thought that $1/\mu$ is the expectation for the first since the events are coming as poisson processes and their interarrivals times are exponential. So for the $n$ events it is $n/\mu$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If their distributions are consecutive (i.e. time for the second does not start until the first is done and so on) then you are correct.

If their distributions are concurrent (i.e. time for each of them starts with $t=0$) and they are independent, then the expected time for the first to occur is $\frac{1}{n\mu}$, the expected time between the first and the second occurrence is   $\frac{1}{(n-1)\mu}$ and so on up to the expected time between the penultimate and the final occurrence is   $\frac{1}{\mu}$ by the memoryless property, making the total time $\dfrac1\mu H_n$ where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Comment: IF they are parallel then why it is not $1/\mu$ for the $n$ events to complete since the time for 1 equals the time for $n$ as they are processed in parallel?

Comment: Because if in parallel, though the first to occur takes an expected $\frac{1}{n\mu}$, you then have have only $n-1$ remaining and so the rate gets smaller pushing the expected time up.

Comment: I still cannot get it.Something in parallel means they all start at the same time and finish at the same time, so is like waiting the execution of 1 job which is $1/\mu$

Comment: They may finish at different times.  Imagine $n$ lightbulbs lit at the same time and waiting for them all to blow each having exponential distributions with the same rate $\mu$.

Comment: Now it is clear thanx